# How to compute catalan numbers with n=100 in C/C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm

My output's false when n is larger than 20. So i need help to compute Catalan's number C(n) with n is smaller than 100

Comment: What is a Catalan number?

Comment: You need to show a [mcve] so that we are able to tell you what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate result for large input values, you have to treat huge integers (larger than any build-in type like int64 (long long)). Big integer arithmetics support is included in some languages like C# and Python.

In C++ you should use some library like [GMP](https://gmplib.org), Boost.Multiprecision, or some lightweight library (because you need only addition and multiplication).

```
 #include <gmp.h>
 mpz_t a, b;                 
 mpz_init_set_str (a, "191999293783437378367363763763"argv[1], 10);   
 mpz_init_set_str (b, "44766484748782378237827328-1829087234976123097", 10);
 mpz_add (t, a, b);
```

It is quite possible to write implementation of these operations by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Call the function through a `for` loop

```
unsigned long int catalan(unsigned int n){

  if (n <= 1) return 1; 

  unsigned long int res = 0; 

  for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
      res += catalan(i)*catalan(n-i-1); 

  return res; 
}
```

Comment: But, when n=100, the result is 896519947090131496687170070074100632420837521538745909320

Comment: @know dont So you need some big numbers library like GMP

Comment: You already have got clear solution. Now learn GMP (or Boost.Multiprecision or some lightweight library with bigint support) and use summation and multiplication. (Some languages like Python and C# have in-built big integers)

Comment: @know dont  I have re-read question and answer. The last does not answer you question because you emphasized on n=100 input. It was worth to show your code to exclude such answers.